# jQuery filter() on selector with .on delegated event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

is there any way to use a jQuery selector in a delegated event with .on() ?
And how would you select only immediate children in the selector ?
Below is a sample of code : I'd like to filter only immediate `<div>` children of the `<section>` element, with the requirement that at least one of their `<p>` children contains the word «hello».
In the example, only the second `<div>` would be filtered. The problem is that other `<div>` can be added afterwards, so the event must be delegated.

The use of the .live() method made it more simple imho, as I could have used :

`$('section > div').filter(function(){return /hello/.test(p) }).live('mouseenter', function(){ ... })`

But as it's deprecated now, its replacement .on() only allows pure CSS-like selectors in delegated events.
Has anyone got any idea on how to filter these elements based on the 2 aforementioned conditions (immediate children & `<p>` contain hello) ?
Thanks

```
<section>
    <div>
        <p>abc</p>
        <div>
            <p>def</p>
            <p>hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>hello world</p>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

**EDIT :** I forgot to add my JS sample, and I'm modifying the condition a little bit so that p:contains('hello') does not suffice as a selector.

```
$('section').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
    }
},
    $('div').filter(function(){
        var p = $(this).children('p').filter(function(){
            return /hello/.test($(this).text());
        });
        return p.length > 2;
    })
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('section').on('mouseenter', '> div > p:contains("hello")', function(){ ... })
```

to have the event on the div, you'll have to set the condition inside the function

```
  $('section').on('mouseenter', '> div', function(){ 
      if ($(this).find("> p:contains("hello")").get(0)) {

         // ...
        }
   })
```

It was laziness as i always do it in my code : it's better to attach event to document and delegate; jquery works way way faster that way + you can add element dynamically without worrying of whether event will be triggered or not (it will)

```
 $(document).on(...
```

Comment: yes but after rereading the question maybe the op want the event on the div editing...

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers, but as Jan said, it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/WP7aW/ >> Both divs are «background-colored» when mouse is over.

Comment: @rgandoin your fiddle actually shows it _does_ work, even if the behavior is not as desired.

Comment: @JanDvorak ISTR reading in the jQuery forums that naked `> foo` selectors without a specified parent were going to be deprecated.

Comment: honestly i don't know, as a guess i'd say probably not... @rgandoin what does not work ? if you mean the event on the div see edited answer

Comment: @Alnitak Why would they be deprecated?

Comment: @JanDvorak because they're not legal selectors.  I'll try and find the reference.

Comment: @JanDvorak, no it doesn't work since both divs see their backgrounds turn to red. Or the section > div > div shouldn't.

Comment: @rgandoin, one after the other only & it's not the div it's the p in your fiddle

Comment: @rgandoin updated the fiddle. I originally used `div` instead of `>div` http://jsfiddle.net/WP7aW/2/

Comment: @JanDvorak hmm, not deprecated yet, and the API manual appears to have removed the future deprecation warning - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/will-immediate-child-selector-be-deprecated

Comment: @JanDvorak post your fiddle as answer, more straightforward

Comment: Thanks Jan, ok now its works, I didn't know that you could naked `> selector` as Alnitak says (though I don't know if it's deprecated/illegal or not). However, I modified the condition a bit, all I want to know is if there's any way to use something else than a string as the selector.

Comment: Thanks @mikakun, so I guess you cannot do otherwise but to use conditions.

Comment: @rgandoin ; yes i can since Jan Dvorak :has(>...) is working but it's his answer

Comment: It is not good approach to use `document` in event delegation all the time.We should use the parent element of the target when we could which would certainly be the faster way.

Comment: @techie_28 no i don't agree, it's very fast & useful but obviously as long as you declare an object  first line `$doc=$(document)` ;that'll be your app object & only global var of your script using then `$doc` in your code. main pro is you don't ever have to worry about dom modification (append/remove on user interactions) & event handling since they are linked to the app object. it also uses less memory than to create many objects with their own event handlers.

Comment: @techie_28 also to ease the browser work you want to be precise in the way you delegate indicating as much as possible the full way to the element (` .page > .div2 > .div3 > p` ). the less precise the longest the search.

Comment: @mikakun Im just talking about traversal here `jQuery(document).on('click','p'.....)` would be slower then `jQuery('#parentDIV').on('click','p'.....)`.. depends on DOM obviously but normally the later one should be faster & better way.

Comment: fastest & less memory usage is `$doc.on(click, parents p...)`; $("parent") is maximum slow. `$doc.find("parent")` is in fact faster than $(parent); you should benchmark until you understand jquery is nice abstraction but you want to call it as less as possible to keep ur app efficient. (hence delegating is crucial)

Answer (score 2):

You can use naked combinators to target the context' children, even in the `has` pseudo-class:

```
$('section').on('mouseenter', '> div:has(> p:contains("hello"))', ...
```

However, It is recommended to avoid them (incompatible with `querySelectorAll`). Consider (only one naked combinator instead of two):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'section > div:has( > p:contains("hello"))`, ...
```

Your second filter (div that has more than two children with the text "hello") is a bit wilder in CSS, but still possible:

```
$('section').on('mouseenter', 'div:has(>'+
  '  p:contains("hello") '+
  '~ p:contains("hello") '+
  '~ p:contains("hello") '+
')', ...
```

If all else fails, you can do prefiltering via selectors and a main filter inside the handler:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'section > div', function(){
  if($(this).children('p:contains("hello")').length > 2){
    ...
  }
})
```

Even an `is` with callback will work:

```
function valid (){...}

$(document).on('mouseenter', 'section > div', function(){
  if($(this).is(valid)){
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, I'll go for the if condition solution, less «wild» as you say ;-)

Comment: @rgandoin note that you can get rid of naked combinators and other non-nativeties altogether when using an explicit condition. Delegating to `document` seems like a good idea anyways.